# python subprocess.check_output cant be decoded

Tags: python, character-encoding, subprocess

I want to save the output of the tree command to a variable via subprocess.check_output() but every charset gives me an error or doesent decode the output correctly.

Python3

Windows10

```
from subprocess import check_output  
from time import sleep  
tree = check_output("tree", shell=True).decode("utf-8") 
print(tree)  
sleep(200) 
----------------------------------------------------------- 
error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\failo\Desktop\test.py", line 4, in <module>
tree = check_output("tree", shell=True).decode("utf-8") 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 65: invalid continuation byte –
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of the code and stacktrace/error? :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to here, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output from `tree` uses Windows line-drawing characters to show the tree structure. These characters are defined in codepage 850. But your code is assuming that the output from `tree` is encoded as UTF-8. The error message is telling you that that assumption about the encoding is wrong. Do this instead:

```
check_output("tree", shell=True).decode("cp850")
```

That gives me this output from the `print()` call:

```
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 12E3-7FA7
    C:.
    ├───DLLs
    ├───Doc
    ├───include
    │   ├───cpython
    │   ├───internal
    │   └───pygame
    ... etc ...
```

Comment: Does this count for everything that is outputted in the console?
btw. thanks allot, you gave me the answer I was looking for hours!

Comment: By default the Windows console uses codepage 850. But you can change that with the `chcp` command. You can even do `chcp 65000` which will change it to a subset of Unicode (no emoji support).